# How to create Multivalue Person property in Organization Profile

Tags: user-profile-property

I need to create a new multivalued person property in the Organization profile. I thought it'd be simple, since there are already properties like that in the Edit Organization Profile form (Organization Leaders and Organization Members). But they don't show up as property, we only see them in the Edit page.

I tried doing it with the Manage Organization Properties form, but I can only add a single value person field.

I tried by code, but got an exception:

> There is no multivalue support for 'Person' type.

How can I add a custom property with multiple person in an Organization Profile, just like the Organization Members?